# Total children values based on parent

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have 2 tables: `table1`,`table2`

```
Parent  Child  Point            Parent     Total
a       b       100               a          0(default)   (result = 1050)
b       c       200               b          0            (result = 950)
c       d       250               c          0            (result = 750)
d       e       500
```

The result in `table2` should be sum of the children points based on parent in `table1`.

```
a---b---c---d---e
```

I tried many times but cant figure out.

```
UPDATE table2 set Total=???
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "based on child and parent"?

Comment: Sum of points based on child.For example, the total of a in table2 is 1050

Comment: Table2 has your result. But how are you computing the sum based on table1? In table1, a has only one child with 100 points

Comment: The result is based on how many child that the parent has and total all.For example, a has total 4 child which are b,c,d,e but different level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [recursive CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html):

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   SELECT parent, child, point AS total
   FROM   tbl1

   UNION ALL
   SELECT c.parent, t.child, c.total + t.point
   FROM   cte  c
   JOIN   tbl1 t ON t.parent = c.child
   )
SELECT *
FROM   cte
```

Answer (score 0):

It hurts my brain... The below should work for you, note that it is very rough and you will want to streamline it.

```
DECLARE @parent NCHAR(1), @child NCHAR(1), @runningTotal INT
SET @parent = 'a' -- set starting parent here
DECLARE myCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT [Parent], [Child], [Point] FROM table1 WHERE [Parent] = @parent
OPEN myCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @parent, @child, @runningTotal
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE [Parent] = @child)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @point INT
        SELECT @parent = [Parent], @child = [Child], @point = [Point] FROM table1 WHERE [Parent] = @child
        SET @runningTotal = @runningTotal + @point
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        BREAK
    END
END
CLOSE myCursor
DEALLOCATE myCursor
SELECT @runningTotal
```

Comment: That is not valid for Postgres

Comment: I didn't note the question tag and only tested with SQL Server, for other database systems it will need some changes - just an idea to solve the problem.

Comment: Even in SQL Server it would be an inefficient solution (as SQL Server also supports recursive queries. A cursor based approach will always be slower than a set-based approach)