# How can I stop my Postgres recusive CTE from indefinitely looping?

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

**Background**

I'm running Postgres 11 on CentOS 7.
I recently learned the basics of recursive CTEs in Postgres thanks to S-Man's answer to [my recent  question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66488482/how-can-i-write-a-sql-query-to-calculate-the-quantity-of-components-sold-with-th/66488758#66488758).

**The problem**

While working on a closely related issue (counting parts sold within bundles and assemblies) and using this recursive CTE, I ran into a problem where the query looped indefinitely and never completed.

I tracked this down to the presence of non-spurious 'self-referential' entries in the `relator` table, i.e. rows with the same value for `parent_name` and `child_name`.

I know that these are the source of the problem because when I recreated the situation with test tables and data, the undesired looping behavior occurred when these rows were present, and disappeared when these rows were absent *or* when `UNION` (which excludes duplicate returned rows) was used in the CTE rather than `UNION ALL` .

I think the data model itself probably needs adjusting so that these 'self-referential' rows aren't necessary, but for now, what I need to do is *get this query to return the desired data on completion and stop looping*.

How can I achieve this result?  All guidance much appreciated!

**Tables and test data**

```
CREATE TABLE the_schema.names_categories (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    created_at TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT now(),
    thing_name TEXT NOT NULL, 
    thing_category TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE the_schema.relator (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    created_at TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT now(),
    parent_name TEXT NOT NULL, 
    child_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    child_quantity INTEGER NOT NULL 
);


/* NOTE: listing_name below is like an alias of a relator.parent_name as it appears in a catalog, 
required to know because it is these listing_names that are reflected by sales.sold_name */

CREATE TABLE the_schema.catalog_listings ( 
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    created_at TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT now(),
    listing_name TEXT NOT NULL, 
    parent_name TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE the_schema.sales (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    created_at TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT now(),    
    sold_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    sold_quantity INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE VIEW the_schema.relationships_with_child_category AS (
    SELECT 
    c.listing_name, 
    r.parent_name,
    r.child_name, 
    r.child_quantity,
    n.thing_category AS child_category
    FROM 
    the_schema.catalog_listings c
    INNER JOIN 
    the_schema.relator r 
    ON c.parent_name = r.parent_name
    INNER JOIN 
    the_schema.names_categories n 
    ON r.child_name = n.thing_name 
);

INSERT INTO the_schema.names_categories (thing_name, thing_category)
VALUES ('parent1', 'bundle'), ('child1', 'assembly'), ('child2', 'assembly'),('subChild1', 'component'), 
('subChild2', 'component'), ('subChild3', 'component');

INSERT INTO the_schema.catalog_listings (listing_name, parent_name)
VALUES ('listing1', 'parent1'), ('parent1', 'child1'), ('parent1','child2'), ('child1', 'child1'), ('child2', 'child2');

INSERT INTO the_schema.catalog_listings (listing_name, parent_name)
VALUES ('parent1', 'child1'), ('parent1','child2');


/* note the two 'self-referential' entries  */
INSERT INTO the_schema.relator (parent_name, child_name, child_quantity)
VALUES ('parent1', 'child1', 1),('child1', 'subChild1', 1), ('child1', 'subChild2', 1)
('parent1', 'child2', 1),('child2', 'subChild1', 1), ('child2', 'subChild3', 1), ('child1', 'child1', 1), ('child2', 'child2', 1);

INSERT INTO the_schema.sales (sold_name, sold_quantity)
VALUES ('parent1', 1), ('parent1', 2), ('listing1', 1);
```

**The present query, loops indefinitely with the required UNION ALL**

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT 
        s.sold_name,
        s.sold_quantity,
        r.child_name,
        r.child_quantity,
        r.child_category as category
    FROM 
        the_schema.sales s
    JOIN the_schema.relationships_with_child_category r
    ON s.sold_name = r.listing_name

    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT
        cte.sold_name,
        cte.sold_quantity,
        r.child_name,
        r.child_quantity,
        r.child_category
    FROM cte
    JOIN the_schema.relationships_with_child_category r 
    ON cte.child_name = r.parent_name

)
SELECT
    child_name,
    SUM(sold_quantity * child_quantity)
FROM cte
WHERE category = 'component'
GROUP BY child_name
;
```

Comment: Please look into relationships_with_child_category table. Are those data valid? How the relationship is maintained? In column four listing_name , parent_name and child_name have same value ("child1").

Comment: Please look into table catalog_listings and relator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **catalog_listings** table listing_name and parent_name is same for **child1** and **child2**
In **relator** table parent_name and child_name is also same for **child1** and **child2**

These rows are creating cycling recursion.

Just remove those two rows from both the tables:

```
delete from catalog_listings where id in (4,5)
delete from relator where id in (7,8)
```

Then your desired output will be as below:

| child_name | sum |
| --- | --- |
| subChild2 | 8 |
| subChild3 | 8 |
| subChild1 | 16 |

Is this the result you are looking for?

If you can't delete the rows you can use below add parent_name<>child_name condition to avoid those rows:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT 
        s.sold_name,
        s.sold_quantity,
        r.child_name,
        r.child_quantity,
        r.child_category as category
    FROM 
        the_schema.sales s
    JOIN the_schema.relationships_with_child_category r
    ON s.sold_name = r.listing_name and r.parent_name <>r.child_name

    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT
        cte.sold_name,
        cte.sold_quantity,
        r.child_name,
        r.child_quantity,
        r.child_category
    FROM cte
    JOIN the_schema.relationships_with_child_category r 
    ON cte.child_name = r.parent_name and r.parent_name <>r.child_name

)
SELECT
    child_name,
    SUM(sold_quantity * child_quantity)
FROM cte
WHERE category = 'component'
GROUP BY child_name    ;
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't read your question carefully. You already mentioned the problem. Now do you just need to get this result without deleting rows?

Comment: That's correct, thanks a bunch for your help!  The `r.parent_name <>r.child_name` did the trick, looping stopped.

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to avoid infinite recursion simply by using `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`.

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) describes the implementation:

> 1. Evaluate the non-recursive term. For `UNION` (but not `UNION ALL`), discard duplicate rows. Include all remaining rows in the result of the recursive query, and also place them in a temporary working table.
> 2. So long as the working table is not empty, repeat these steps:
>
>    1. Evaluate the recursive term, substituting the current contents of the working table for the recursive self-reference. For `UNION` (but not `UNION ALL`), discard duplicate rows and rows that duplicate any previous result row. Include all remaining rows in the result of the recursive query, and also place them in a temporary intermediate table.
>    2. Replace the contents of the working table with the contents of the intermediate table, then empty the intermediate table.

"Getting rid of the duplicates" should cause the intermediate table to be empty at some point, which ends the iteration.